# Javascript: script reference with no children not working

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a jQuery templates example work on a SharePoint web part.

I narrowed my problem down to the following:

This WORKS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/ServerComponents/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/ServerComponents/jquery.tmpl.min.js" ></script>
```

but this DOESN'T:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/ServerComponents/jquery-latest.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/ServerComponents/jquery.tmpl.min.js" />
```

Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because `script` is not a self-closing tag. You always need the closing tag.

See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT):

> *Start tag: **required**, End tag: **required***

Comment: Thanks - good to get a little slap in the face and get back to RTFM :-)